# JavaScript - Picking specific data from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object, key

I'm trying to pick specific data from my JSON response which looks like this;

```
{
   "status": "success",
   "reservations": [
      {
         "id": "26630",
         "subject": "Subject",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T06:05:12",
         "startDate": "2017-05-16T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-05-16T09:45:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "2408",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "3020",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "realizationCode",
               "name": "realizationName"
            },
            {
               "id": "48",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "roomCode",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "buildingCode",
                  "name": "buildngName"
               },
               "name": "RoomName (PC)"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "21173",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T06:05:20",
         "startDate": "2017-05-16T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-05-16T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "3115",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "realizationCode",
               "name": "realizationName"
            },
            {
               "id": "2584",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "52",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "roomCode",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "buildingCode",
                  "name": "buildingName"
               },
               "name": "roomName (classroom)"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      }
   ]
}
```

I've already used `JSON.parse()` to make it into an object and went through it with `for-loops`;

```
var json = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
    if (json.reservations[i].resources != null) {
        for (var j = 0; j < json.reservations[i].resources.length; j++) {

             var reservations = json.reservations[i];
             var resources = json.reservations[i].resources[j];  

         }                              
     }
}
```

So I would need to pick out the room names before the `"description"` key name:

```
"name": "roomName (PC)"
"name": "roomName (classroom)"
```

I've kept the JSON response a lot shorter for simplicity's sake but usually there's many more of these room names. The idea is to get all the room names from the JSON response body and push them to an array and just printing them out in order like this;

```
roomName (PC)
roomName (classroom)
```

Any quick and effective way to do this?

Comment: The method `Array.prototype.filter` may help you here.

Comment: I think you might want to use lodash.js or underscore.js for this.. It's really helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first iterate over the `json.reservations` array with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and then iterate again over `r.resources` and make a [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) if the expression: `new RegExp(/roomName/, 'i').test(r.name)` is satisfied.

Notice that in your `json` array have lowercase `"name": "roomName (classroom)"` and uppercase `"name": "RoomName (PC)"`, so the [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) will not check case sensitive with the flag `i` and finally the [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) will check if `roomName` is in the `r.name`.

Code:

```js
var json = {"status": "success","reservations": [{"id": "26630","subject": "Subject","modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T06:05:12","startDate": "2017-05-16T08:00:00","endDate": "2017-05-16T09:45:00","resources": [{"id": "2408","type": "student_group","code": "groupCode","name": "groupName"},{"id": "3020","type": "realization","code": "realizationCode","name": "realizationName"},{"id": "48","type": "room","code": "roomCode","parent": {"id": "2","type": "building","code": "buildingCode","name": "buildngName"},"name": "RoomName (PC)"}],"description": ""},{"id": "21173","subject": "subjectName","modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T06:05:20","startDate": "2017-05-16T08:00:00","endDate": "2017-05-16T16:00:00","resources": [{"id": "3115","type": "realization","code": "realizationCode","name": "realizationName"},{"id": "2584","type": "student_group","code": "groupCode","name": "groupName"},{"id": "52","type": "room","code": "roomCode","parent": {"id": "2","type": "building","code": "buildingCode","name": "buildingName"},"name": "roomName (classroom)"}],"description": ""}]},
    result = [],
    regex = new RegExp(/roomName/, 'i');

json.reservations.forEach(function (r) {
  r.resources.forEach(function (r) {
    regex.test(r.name) && result.push({
      name: r.name
    });
  });
})

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use such way:

```js
const arrays = json.reservations
  .filter(reservation => reservation.resources)
  .map(reservation =>
    reservation.resources.map(resource => resource.name)
  )
;

const names = [].concat.apply([], arrays);
```

Array flatten taken from this question: [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: also you can use lodash to flatten arrays

Comment: That's true, but I prefer your current answer (some explanation would be nice) as the OP didn't ask for a library, nor was it tagged or used.

Comment: basically, you are getting array of arrays with names and then flattening result array

Comment: If you're answer is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript surely then this question is a duplicate?

Comment: no, there is only this part: `const names = [].concat.apply([], arrays);`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
var a = {
   "status": "success",
   "reservations": [
      {
         "id": "26630",
         "subject": "Subject",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T06:05:12",
         "startDate": "2017-05-16T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-05-16T09:45:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "2408",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "3020",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "realizationCode",
               "name": "realizationName"
            },
            {
               "id": "48",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "roomCode",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "buildingCode",
                  "name": "buildngName"
               },
               "name": "RoomName (PC)"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "21173",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T06:05:20",
         "startDate": "2017-05-16T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-05-16T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "3115",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "realizationCode",
               "name": "realizationName"
            },
            {
               "id": "2584",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "52",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "roomCode",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "buildingCode",
                  "name": "buildingName"
               },
               "name": "roomName (classroom)"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      }
   ]
}

var b = [];
a.reservations.forEach(function(item){ 
    item.resources.forEach(function(obj){  
        if(obj.type == "room"){
            b.push(obj.name)
        }  
    })  
});
console.log(b); //outputs desired array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonStr = "{ \"status\": \"success\", \"reservations\": [ { \"id\": \"26630\", \"subject\": \"Subject\", \"modifiedDate\": \"2017-05-16T06:05:12\", \"startDate\": \"2017-05-16T08:00:00\", \"endDate\": \"2017-05-16T09:45:00\", \"resources\": [ { \"id\": \"2408\", \"type\": \"student_group\", \"code\": \"groupCode\", \"name\": \"groupName\" }, { \"id\": \"3020\", \"type\": \"realization\", \"code\": \"realizationCode\", \"name\": \"realizationName\" }, { \"id\": \"48\", \"type\": \"room\", \"code\": \"roomCode\", \"parent\": { \"id\": \"2\", \"type\": \"building\", \"code\": \"buildingCode\", \"name\": \"buildngName\" }, \"name\": \"RoomName (PC)\" } ], \"description\": \"\" }, { \"id\": \"21173\", \"subject\": \"subjectName\", \"modifiedDate\": \"2017-05-16T06:05:20\", \"startDate\": \"2017-05-16T08:00:00\", \"endDate\": \"2017-05-16T16:00:00\", \"resources\": [ { \"id\": \"3115\", \"type\": \"realization\", \"code\": \"realizationCode\", \"name\": \"realizationName\" }, { \"id\": \"2584\", \"type\": \"student_group\", \"code\": \"groupCode\", \"name\": \"groupName\" }, { \"id\": \"52\", \"type\": \"room\", \"code\": \"roomCode\", \"parent\": { \"id\": \"2\", \"type\": \"building\", \"code\": \"buildingCode\", \"name\": \"buildingName\" }, \"name\": \"roomName (classroom)\" } ], \"description\": \"\" } ] }";
var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var array = [];  
for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
    if (json.reservations[i].resources != null) {

        for (var j = 0; j < json.reservations[i].resources.length; j++) {
             var resource = json.reservations[i].resources[j];
             if (resource.type === "room") {
                 if (array.indexOf("code")) {
                     array.push(resource.name);
                 }                                     
             }                                                                                         
         }

     }
}
 console.log(array);
```

output in console. Please check..

(2) ["RoomName (PC)", "roomName (classroom)"]0: "RoomName (PC)"1: "roomName (classroom)"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)